# Oracle Database 19.3 on Windows: Howto impdp or expdp from a UNC path in Windows?

Tags: oracle, datapump

With oracle database release 18.3 it is possible to use a unc path as a directory in windows and pump a database pump from this directory with impdp.

Example:

```
C:\>sqlplus system/passwd@exampledb
C:\>create directory DUMPS as '\\storage\dir';
C:\>exit
C:\>impdp system/passwd@exampledb directory=DUMPS dumpfile=example.dmp logfile=example-imp.log
... just works as expected
```

With oracle database release 19.3, the same impdp instruction produces the following output:

```
c:\>impdp system/passwd@exampledb directory=DUMPS dumpfile=example.dmp logfile=example-imp.log

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39155: error expanding dump file name "\\storage\dir\example.dmp"
ORA-48128: opening of a symbolic link is disallowed
```

I use the same account to run the oracle database service in the example for 18.3 and 19.3. Therefore, I assume that network or credential issues are not an explanation for my observation.

Is this a changed behaviour between Oracle Database Release 18.3 and 19.3, and did I miss the description of this changed behaviour in the release notes?
Or am I missing a setting introduced with 19.3 to enable the use of UNC shares in a DIRECTORY? Or something else I did wrong?

I tried to use the share as drive letter as follows:

```
C:\>net use p: \\storage\dir /persistent:yes /user:myuser 
dir p:
... list of files // network access works well 

C:\>sqlplus system/passwd@exampledb  
create directory DUMPS as 'P:\'; 
exit
C:\>impdp system/passwd@exampledb directory=DUMPS dumpfile=example.dmp logfile=example-imp.log 

... ORA-39002: invalid operation 
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file. 
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Now impdp complains about the log file. The problem also appears without using the impdp logfile= parameter.

Comment: try mapping the share as a drive letter

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried to use the share as drive letter as follows:
```
C:\>net use p: \\storage\dir /persistent:yes /user:myuser 
dir p:
... list of files // network access works well
C:\>sqlplus system/passwd@exampledb
create directory DUMPS as 'P:\';
exit
C:\>impdp system/passwd@exampledb directory=DUMPS dumpfile=example.dmp logfile=example-imp.log
...
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```
Now impdp complains about the log file. The problem also appears without using the impdp logfile= parameter.

Comment: Did you execute grant read,write to  <your user who is importing> on DUMPS;

Comment: I use the system user in this example - system should not need a grand as far as I know.

Comment: correct. This  error is typical for the database does not have OS permissions on the folder. Suggest you create a directory as a folder and grant read write to the service account the database is running under

Comment: This is the workaround I am using so far. But in this cas it is necessary that I copy the database dump from share to local disk before I am able to pump. This is doable, but more time and space-consuming than the direct approach using an unc path. But I am wondering why using an unc path works fine in 18.3 and does not in 19.3.

Comment: I suggest there may be issues granting read write to an networked drive in windows that would be resolved by creating a directory in a folder in the drive.  Grant OS permissions to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the below interesting:

http://christian-gohmann.de/2019/05/19/symbolic-links-in-directory-objects-not-permitted-with-oracle-18c-19c/

Long story short, I had the same issue, then after setting the parameter below and restarting the database, Data Pump was able to use the network share.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_disable_directory_link_check" = TRUE SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Comment: A shame we have to take the security hit because of what appears to be a bug. Always wanted to see what code is being run that's making this determination; I can't even see the "guts" of the "DBMS_UTILITY.has_symlink" pkg fcn, which may just be relying on the specific "ORA" error signifying a symlink was found and not doing any specific checking. Could be a Java class to deploy as an OS-specific "decorator". Anyone know how to get at this code that's doing this detection in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on which user the Oracle Database is running as (see Windows service named OracleServiceXXX - where XXX is your database SID). The datapump operation runs in the context of the database, so the user running the database must also have file system permissions on the UNC share. Some times the Window service is started as "Local System" which probably don't have many remote privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Came here looking for ORA-48128 in Oracle 19.3

As a follow-up to @"Balazs Papp" answer above, you can get the same error message for a mounted directory (hard drive hard mounted to `C:\mnt\Datapump` instead of a letter), and the

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_disable_directory_link_check" = TRUE SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

works.

It is almost certainly a bug in Oracle.

Comment: I actually have not come across the error with drive letters, unless the path had a real OS symlink - or unless the path had a forward slash in it; that seems to trip that ""utldirsymlink.sql/"DBMS_UTILITY.[directory_]has_symlink pkg fcns. Seems to be a few bugs throughout.